# Editing JqxComboBox inside JqxGrid issue

Tags: jqxgrid, jqxwidgets, jqxcombobox

How do I edit(add new) item in jqxComboBox inside jqxGrid.
Currently when I add new item in it, its getting blank.

Comment: show your code, its difficult to know whats wrong if we dont know the code ..

Comment: Thnx for reply and reminder. Its fixed... http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/editing-jqxcombobox-inside-jqxgrid-issue/